# issue with jquery panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am new to jQuery mobile.  I am trying to set a panel for my application but the panel is showing before on-click of menu button.  How can I show the panel on click of menu button?

My code is as follows:

```
<div data-role="page" id="homePage">

    <div data-role="panel" id="navpanel" data-theme="a" data-display="overlay" data-position="right">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-corners="false"> <a href="#" data-role="button">Business</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">Numbers</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">Money</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">People</a></div>
    </div>

          <div data-role="header" id="header" data-theme="a">
              <a id="bars-button" data-icon="bars" class="ui-btn-left" style="margin-top:10px;" href="#navpanel">Menu</a>
              <h1>
                  Gps Coordinates
              </h1>
          </div>
</div>
```

This is my scripting code:

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var header = $('[data-role=header]').outerHeight();
    var panel = $('.ui-panel').height();
    var panelheight = panel - header;
    $('.ui-panel').css({
                       'top': header,
                       'min-height': panelheight
                       });
</script>
```

Css:

```
.ui-panel-inner {
            padding:0px;
        }
        .ui-controlgroup {
            margin:0;
        }
        #header {
            height:54px;
        }
        #bars-button {
            margin:7px;
        }
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Business, numbers, money, and people are my menu list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can't you bind click event to menu button and write show/ hide logic in it?

Comment: i dono which jquery version you using .. anyway everything working fine .. check this out http://jsfiddle.net/SkKVX/129/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery mobile panel is not hidden default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441845/jquery-mobile-panel-is-not-hidden-default)